# Error message with git pull?

Tags: java, git, version-control

I am working in `git` and if I do a `git pull` in my `develop` branch I get the following error. How can I fix this so it stops?

```
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.develop.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me, either. Please
specify which branch you want to use on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
use something like the following in your configuration file:
    [branch "develop"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

    [remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to specify what branch you want to pull. For example, if you want to pull branch `master` from remote `origin`, you have to use the command

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your local branch to track the remote develop branch.

Assuming your remote is named origin, and the remote branch shares the same name you can do this via `git branch --set-upsteam-to origin/develop develop`

You should then be able to do `git pull` without specifying a remote/branch (assuming you have the develop branch checked out!)

Comment: It seems the correct command is `git branch --set-upsteam-to develop origin/develop`